# php form sending blank emails?

Tags: php, forms, email

I am having some issues with a client receiving blank forms through my email.

I am using the following form

```
 <form method="get" action="javascript:contactForm()" class="form">
            <div class="alertForm"><!-- Error's go in here --></div>
            <div class="innerForm">
                <div class="placeholder">Your Name</div>
              <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" placeholder="">
                <div class="placeholder">Your Phone Number</div>
              <input type="text" name="number" value="" id="number" placeholder="">
              <select name="time" id="time">
                <option value="null">Please Select A Time</option>
                <option value="09:00 - 11:00">09:00 - 11:00</option>
                <option value="11:00 - 13:00">11:00 - 13:00</option>
                <option value="13:00 - 15:00">13:00 - 15:00</option>
                <option value="15:00 - 17:00">15:00 - 17:00</option>
                <option value="17:00 - 19:00">17:00 - 19:00</option>
              </select>
              <input type="submit" value="Call Me Back">
            </div>
          </form>
```

And the PHP post

```
     $name = $_POST['name']; $number = $_POST['number']; $time = $_POST['time'];
     $subject = "[CALLBACK] ".$name." - ".$number;
     $to = "clown@thecircus.co.uk";
     $headers = "From:" . "website@thecircus.co.uk";
     $message = $name." would like you to call them back on ".$number." between ".$time;

     if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){ echo "We will call you within the time       you've selected. If not today, then the next day.<br><br>Thank you."; }
     else{ echo "Something's gone horribly wrong! PANIC."; }
```

If i try it it seems wo to work fine - however i am receiving about 7 blank emails per day. I am unsure if these are SPAM or they are actually contact forms however have lost their data?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It must be a spam, include capcha to your form

Comment: Don't use `<div>`s for labels, use `<label>`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form `method` is set to `get` but you're trying to access `$_POST` variables in your PHP. Switch your form to `method="post"` or use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` (though I'd recommend using POST).

But, your should also add some server-side validation to your form. At least check that something has been entered into your form fields.